# Pass input query for Hadoop job with Date filter (mongo.input.query)

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I am working with Hadoop to write Map Reduce jobs for my application.

I found I could set query condition before the job gets executed by editing the property `mongo.input.query`.

But when I tried to give the below query (added ISODate for MongoDB concern)

```
  <property>
    <name>mongo.input.query</name>
    <value>{ "created_at": { "$gt": ISODate("2013-06-12") } }</value>
    <value></value>
  </property>
```

Actually this query works fine when running in MongoVUE query console, but when running with a Hadoop job it shows like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided JSON String is not representable/parseable as a DBObject.
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:
{ "created_at": { "$gt": ISODate("2013-06-12") } }
```

Any suggestion would be helpful to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [extended json](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) for Dates and other datatypes which aren't part of native JSON.
For example:

```
 {"created_at":{"$gt":{"$date":1182470400000}}}
```

(using the long representation of the date).

Comment: I tried to pass this when running hadoop job `hadoop jar path_to_jar.jar -Dmongo.input.query=' {"created_at":{"$gt":{"$date":"1370784120000"}}}' path_to_config_class`, (The date refers to `2013/06/09 Sunday` and I have data in db which have created at greater than this date.. but its not working

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks. @balanv try not putting quotes around the number. E.g.: {"created_at":{"$gt":{"$date":1370784120000}}}